# Unsorted HTML lists not working

Tags: html, templates, tags, html-lists

I have co-written this code:

```
<ul><p>what  are you <i>still</i>  doing  up?</p>
<p>you  waiting  for  <i>me</i>, so we can <em>go</em> to bed <sup><sub>together?</sub></sup></p>

<ul>there is no such thing as  an  unsorted  list  in my world</ul>
<ul>nej  tak  jeg vil  gerne  sove</ul>

<p>you went for a <b>bold</b> move...</p>
<p>camel rider  hidden  in the  sand  snake  flippant  eyebrow  mandrake</p></ul>
```

As a template for a website (called ***Order of the Mouse***) but the unsorted list does not display. How I make the unsorted list display?

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use `<li>` tags to make your list. Like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>there is no such</li>
  <li>thing as an unsorted</li>
  <li>list in my world</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to put the elements of the list in their own `<li>` tags, like this:

```
<ul>
   <li>there is no such thing as  an  unsorted  list  in my world</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may need an `<li>` tag nested between your `<ul></ul>` tags.  Like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>there is no such thing as an unsorted list in my world</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you write unordered lists :

```
<ul>
  <li>Put your text here</li>
  <li>More items....</li>
  <li>....</li>
</ul>
```

Good luck !